# Error: No provider for config

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Receiving the following error. No sure what to do. Importing one of the component library and trying to use into my ionic project.

Library is using Angular 4, Ionic 3.

[Error received after running "ionic-app-scripts serv" in my ionic project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo87m.png)

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 5):

You have a component, directive, pipe, or service that has a constructor parameter `constructor(foo:Config)` but you haven't registered a provider for type `Config`. Angulars DI therefore can't create an instance of this class and instead throws an exception.